# Datagridview with procedure don't update

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have written this procedure in SQL and is working

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[gridcombo] (@tabela int)
as

/*1 Setores */
if  (@tabela=1)
begin
select setor_id, setor_nome  from tbl_setores
end
/*2  Atividade Economica   */
if  (@tabela=2)
begin
SELECT cnae_id, cnae_descricao  FROM tbl_CNAE
end
```

I use this procedure to populate a datagridview in C#

```
    public SqlConnection sqlcon = Tconex.GetConnection();
    public SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter();
    public DataTable dt1 = new DataTable(); 

        SqlParameter tabela = new SqlParameter("@tabela", SqlDbType.Int);
        tabela.Value = 1;
        SqlCommand llena = new SqlCommand("gridcombo", sqlcon);
        llena.Parameters.Add(tabela);
        llena.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        da2.SelectCommand = llena;
        da2.Fill(dt1);
        BindingSource bsource = new BindingSource();
        bsource.DataSource = dt1;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bsource;
        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        sqlcon.Close();
```

When I change the `tabela.value` the datagrid  is populated with one or another table, that works fine.

But I cannot edit the table via datagrid

```
        da2.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommandBuilder(da2).GetUpdateCommand();  
        da2.Update(dt1);
        sqlcon.Close();
```

What am I doing wrong? Why can't I update the table??

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must return your `PrimaryKey` of table in your `SelectCommand`, in order to generate correctly your update command

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Thank's alejandro i'am happy to help you